# Problemas mostrando resultado de queries en express + mongodb

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

Hola estoy tratando de hacer una API que dado unos ids me devuelva un arreglo con cada objeto encontrado. El problema es que la app se rompe cuando consulto la api como se muestra debajo. Quisiera alguien me ayude con lo que esta pasando pues soy nuevo con node.js y no veo donde esta mi error . Gracias

```
http://localhost:3000/calculatePrice?id[0]=1234&qty[0]=2&id[1]=123456&qty[1]=3
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

----------Console-------------

```
   nodemon] restarting due to changes...
   [nodemon] starting `node index.js`
   Listening on port 3000
   { _id: 5acbd85c6116cc38b42b223a,
   id: '1234',
   name: 'perro',
   price: 40,
   __v: 0 }
  1234
  { _id: 5acbda3fac2c811e6cce87fc,
  id: '123456',
  name: 'gato',
  price: 10,
  __v: 0 }
 123456
 events.js:183
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
at ServerResponse.header 


 D:\Programacion\proyects\petStore\node_modules\express\lib\
 response.js:767:10)
 at ServerResponse.send 
(D:\Programacion\proyects\petStore\node_modules\express\lib\
response.js:170:12)
at ServerResponse.json 
 (D:\Programacion\proyects\petStore\node_modules\express\lib\
response.js:267:15)
at Toy.findOne (D:\Programacion\proyects\petStore\index.js:119:10)
at 
D:\Programacion\proyects\petStore\node_modules\mongoose\lib\
model.js:3950:16
at process.nextTick 
(D:\Programacion\proyects\petStore\node_modules\mongoose\lib\
 query.js:2016:28)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

----------------Código API (Schema Mongo)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myDatabase');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var toySchema = new Schema( {
id: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
name: {type: String, required: true},
price: Number
} );


module.exports = mongoose.model('Toy', toySchema);
```

-------Código API index.js---------

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//Aqui configuramos el middleware
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
//Incluimos los modelos
var Toy = require('./Toy.js');

app.use('/calculatePrice', (req, res) => {
const { id, qty } = req.query;
var toy = {};
var toys = [];  
var subtotal = 0;
    toy.identificadores = id;
    toy.cantidades = qty;
    if(Object.keys(toy).length != 0){
        toy.identificadores.map((ident)=>{
        var query = {};
        query.id = ident;
        Toy.findOne(query, (err, juguete)=>{
            if(err){
              res.json(err);
            }else{  
                console.log(juguete);
                console.log(query.id);
                toys.push(juguete);
                res.json(toys);
            }
        });
    });
}else{
    res.json({});
}
});
//Configuracion del servidor
app.listen(3000, () => {
console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No se si sea por la diferencia de `findOne` y `find`

- findOne(): devuelve el primer documento
- find(): devuelve todos los documentos con los que coincida

espero eso te pueda ayudar

[MongoDb Oficial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

Comment: Hola Oropeza perdón por demorar en responder. Acabo de re formular la pregunta y actualice el log para ver si me entienden mejor.